# bootstrap tooltip auto placement in div with overflow-y

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have twitter-bootstrap tooltips on links within a div. The div has its overflow-y set to auto. My issue is that placement: 'auto top' is not respected relative to the div's top. If I scroll down the page (to put the div toward the top of the browser) the auto placement works. So in short I'm wondering if its possible to get the tooltip to react to the div top not the page top.

Here is how I am initiating it...

```js
$("#"+caller).tooltip({html:true,title:resultString,placement:'auto top'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so no need to re-invent a thing :)
just add a fixed position to the tooltip class...

```
.tooltip{
        position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:

```
.tooltip{
        position:fixed;
}


"data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title" data-container="body"
```

Comment: This website is for english questions and answers. Please only answer in english. For spanish (?) use the spanish version of stackoverflow [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

initiating the tooltip like this

```js
$('#example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })
```

you can check it in the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#usage) where they address:

> Tooltip position attempts to automatically change when a parent container has overflow: auto or overflow: scroll like our .table-responsive, but still keeps the original placement’s positioning. To resolve, set the boundary option to anything other than default value, 'scrollParent', such as 'window':